# What are good interactive GUI builder packages for Perl?

Tags: perl, user-interface

I'd like to write some interactive GUIs in Perl. I've used TclTk but it looks dated. I've written QT code for C++, but the PerlTk module hasn't had a release in several years. Googling around I see other possible options.

What are good packages for this, including basic windowing, menus, drawing canvas, scrollbars, and so on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Gtk2](http://developer.gnome.org/) has [glade2](http://glade.gnome.org/) which can write out an XML file usable by [Gtk2::GladeXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Gtk2-GladeXML/GladeXML.pm).  Here is an [example of how to bundle the XML with the app](http://markmail.org/message/7zs6qtmv6u2mpa3g) in the same file.

I misread the question at first.  I thought you wanted a GUI editor for making GUIs (which is what glade2 is).  You can also create GUIs using Gtk2 without glade2:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Gtk2;

Gtk2->init;

my $window = Gtk2::Window->new;
my $vbox   = Gtk2::VBox->new;
my $label  = Gtk2::Label->new("Hello World");
my $button = Gtk2::Button->new("Press me");

$window->add($vbox);
$vbox->add($label);
$vbox->add($button);

$window->set_default_size(200, 200);
$window->signal_connect(
    destroy => sub {
        Gtk2->main_quit;
    }
);

my $i = 0;
$button->signal_connect(
    clicked => sub {
        $label->set_text("button pressed " . ++$i . " times");
    }
);

$window->show_all;

Gtk2->main;
```

Comment: If you need a canvas with this Gnome2::Canvas is the heavyweight anser while Goo::Canvas doesn't have the gnome dependencies.

Answer (score 11):

Try [wxPerl](http://wxperl.sourceforge.net/)!

From the web site:

> wxPerl is an extension module allowing
>   the creation of GUI (Graphical User
>   Interface) from Perl; it is built as a
>   wrapper for the awesome wxWidgets C++
>   GUI toolkit.

Comment: un-awesome, Alien::Wx is horrible, and not supporting file handle events is a deal breaker.

Comment: Thate is also a GUI Builder for wxPerl - wxGlade. Tha advantage of the Wx toolkit also is that it has a native look on on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

Echoing Chas Owens, glade is quite usable with Gtk2 in Perl.  In addition, Gtk2 also supports GtkBuilder files (which you can create the latest glade too).

The main problem with wxPerl (and wxWidgets itself) is that it doesn't let you install file event watchers into its main loop (it only has GUI, Socket and Timer events), unlike Tk and Gtk.

The Qt, Tk and Gtk2 event loops can be used in Perl with AnyEvent, and Gtk2 can be hooked into applications running the Event or Ev mainloop with Glib::Event and Glib::EV modules.

Comment: And POE can be used with AnyEvent, its just that POE is horrible in terms of memory usage and performance.

Comment: Really? s/perl/Perl/?  I was referring to the binary.

Answer (score 4):

A GUI builder for WxPerl would be [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/) or [wxFormBuilder](http://wxformbuilder.org/), both open-source.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably use Gtk2, but Tk is definitely not dead.  The lack of releases is due to the bugs being ironed out over the years.  A lot of people still use it, and it generally works fine.  (Tk's event loop is somewhat silly, but that is a detail that probably shouldn't concern you.)  The only disadvantage is that your GUI looks like it is from 1996, but who cares?

(The `gitk` tool included with git showed that Tk GUIs look fine as long as they're useful.)

Comment: The gitk tool shows why nobody should be using Tk anymore, and I think - to answer the rhetorical question - pretty much everyone cares.

Comment: You think gitk looks fine? Oh, wait, you use linux on an 8 inch screen. :)

Comment: What I mean is that you can whine about the color of the GUI's
background all you want, the fact is that you still get your work done
easily and efficiently.  That means Tk is ugly, not dead.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I was made aware of another GUI toolkit for Perl called [Prima](https://metacpan.org/module/Prima). Its claim to fame is that it was written in C especially for Perl, not a port from TCL or bindings to something else. Assuming you have some rather standard libraries on your system, it will install directly from CPAN and its cross-platform!

David Mertens has been writing a new [plotting library](http://p3rl.org/PDL%3a%3aGraphics%3a%3aPrima) for [PDL](http://pdl.perl.org) using it, and a [REPL](http://p3rl.org/App%3a%3aPrima%3a%3aREPL) too!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding quality of widgets, all three gtk2, wx and qt4 are equally good -- gtk2 is fastest, qt4 has best resolution, whereas wx is somewhere between the two in terms of both the parameters.

But tk is behind all the three both in terms of speed and resolution, but remains firstly because it is the original widget for all unix based interpreted languages, and secondly because it is native-widget of freebsd.

As on today in case of perl, documentation of perl-gtk2 is slightly more developed than both perl-qt4 which is in turn is more developed than wxperl. In fact, if you browse the web, you will find that tutorials for perl-gtk2 is more extensively available than even pygtk (which is also very well established) and ruby-gtk2. In case of python, wxpython documentation leads over PyQt and pygtk, whereas in case of ruby, ruby-qt4 leads over ruby-gtk2 and wxruby. However, others are developing very fast (e.g. ruby-gtk2) and after some time all nine will be equal in all aspects.

The perl-qt4 specific problem is: In case of non-kde desktops, perl-qt4 may not run. I tried running all in ubuntu and sabayon and found that perl-gtk2 and even wxperl (and wxruby also) runs fine whereas I'm not able to run even a single perl-qt4 programs in gnome-desktop where I have installed complete qt4 support without kde.

perl-qt4 asks for installation of not just qt4-libraries, but also kde-desktop libraries. This problem is uniquely perl-qt4-specific, does not exist in case of PyQt and rubyqt4 since they both run fine with qt4 runtime under gnome.

Hence, in this way eight (plus three tk) out of nine options did well (I havent tested PySide yet).

In case of perl-tk, widget is well developed and established and unlike tkinter, pmw and rubytk, its documentation is the best among all of these mentioned above.

But maybe after some time all the documentations become developed and any would become equally good.

After taking a balance between speed, clarity and cross-platform into consideration choose either perl-gtk2, or perl-qt4 or wxperl.

perl-tk, perl-gtk2 and perl-qt4 syntaxes nicely go well with perl programming language syntax, whereas wxperl syntax look more like proper c++ blended into perl which is different from the respective language syntax (just like in case of wxpython and wxruby).

But if you are already keeping in mind that wx code is uniquely different then you can straightaway begin with wxperl.

Otherwise, best way out is: begin with perl-tk, then switch over to perl-gtk2 then perl-qt4 or wxperl alike but make sure that you learn all four instead of only one (the same sequence should also apply to python and ruby too despite the fact that documentation support is reverse, but in case of perl even for this aspect it is same).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a real answer for you, but often you have to consider your deployment targets. Some of the GUI libraries are very nice, but only if you can get them to work on your operating system. I don't necessarily think that all frameworks need to be cross-platform compatible, a very laudable goal to work toward in a perfect world, as long as the one you choose doesn't lock out a significant portion of your users because the foundation GUIs libraries are hard to install or support on a particular platform.

Comment: Wx, Tk, and Gtk2 are all cross platform, of the three Tk is the easiest to get working, followed by Wx, followed by Gtk2.  In my experience the ease of coding goes in reverse order.

Comment: Wx is difficult to get working where there Alien::Wx doesn't work out of tarball (mostly operating systems with sharedlibrary.so.number.number, not sharedlibrary.so), which is strange since few other library using perl modules have that problem.

Comment: Gtk2 is cross-platform only in the sense that the word is meaningless. You either have to use someone's binary package, which pre-supposes something about your setup, or try to compile it yourself and give up.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to let everyone know PerlQt is great and this site has a lot of tutorials on how to use it and lots of examples to download.

[PerlQt Wiki tutorial](http://perlqt.wikidot.com)

PerlQt is a very fast and easy way to create great looking GUI programs using the Qt drag and drop form designer and Perl. PerlQt is powerful enough for advanced developers and easy for beginners as well.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I'm going with is Gtk-Perl. At first I had difficulty installing it, but in the end I found [Camelbox](http://code.google.com/p/camelbox/) Perl+Gtk2 in one package.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `Tk`, but in the last few days I have been playing around with [`Continuity`](http://continuity.tlt42.org/) ([CPAN entry](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Continuity)), a stateful (persistent state per user) web application/server, and it could easily be a way to add "GUI" features into an application, while making it multi-user and portable at the same time.

Edit: At the time I wrote this, I was most interested in the fact that Continuity had its own built-in webserver. This is now true of other webframeworks for Perl as well. I have been using [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) though I hear good things about [Dancer](http://perldancer.org) too.