# What module to use for perl GUI on linux?

Tags: perl, user-interface

I want to build GUI application with perl.

However, there are too many choices and I don't really know what are the advantages/disadvantages.

This page http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=108708 on perlmonks is over 10 years old, so that's not really that helpful.

My target are people using Linux OS, so I don't have to care about interoperability.

Comment: Here is a somewhat more recent thread that may help: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=626246 Also, the answer is probably going to be dependent on what you want to do.

Comment: Hm. Thanks. Just... very simple GUIs, with two, three different dialogues tops.

Comment: Also, this question has a lot of useful information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695722/what-are-good-interactive-gui-builder-packages-for-perl

Comment: Thanks! Write that as an answer and I will accept it presto. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think a link to another question is significant enough to be an answer.  I'm glad it was helpful.